# Cms database licenses Structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures, structure

I'm currently building a big cms.
there is a table that called `posts`

**her columns:**

`licenses_id` `post_id` `title`

now what i want is that when user that has licenses id for example `sSj1j221321`
insert an new post it will search on `posts` table what is the last `post_id` that have the same licenses_id and insert it as post_id + 1.

**how should i do it?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to get the next post_id like this:

1. You can do a query to get the next post_id of the licenses_id like this:

   ```
   SELECT `post_id`+1 AS `next_id` FROM `posts` 
   WHERE `licenses_id`='sSj1j221321' ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 1
   ```
2. Fetch the `next_id` from above, then use it as the `post_id` in your insert query.